# Cannot authorise api to access consumer outlook account

Tags: .net, outlook, authorization, outlook-restapi

I want to write a console application to access my personal outlook address to download emails for a proof of concept. So a full backend scenario, no user interface where a user logs into their own account and grants access the first time they log in. One part of this flow (authorization code flow) requires me to grant access to the account.

So I crafted an authorisation url (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=clientid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read) and logged on with my outlook.com email and then I got an error:

> We're unable to complete your request
>
> Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.

I expected to get a page where I could grant my application access.

*UPDATE* I want to use the [OAuth authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started) so I can use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) to access my mails.

Comment: I can find the settings after login to my hotmail account. And the url is [https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/options/popandimap](https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/options/popandimap), in Options->Mail->Accounts->POP and IMAP.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to use POP or IMAP, I want to use the Microsoft graph rest api.